# Keep branch updated with master GitExtensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

This is my situation:

I'm working on an already published branch since a while and now my branch is starting to be far away from `master` and I do need some of the new things that have been changed on the `master`.

I always keep my local `master` updated doing a `checkout master`, `pull` then `merge origin/master` in order to keep it right at the last merge.

Let's call the "old" branch `bugfix`, now i just want to add the last modifications to `bugfix` WITHOUT merging it to the remote master and keeping it for some other works in the future.

I'm not so used to GIT commands (yet) so I really appreciate if you could give me some instruction on how to do it from GitExtensions GUI.

P.S: I have control on the remote too, how am I going to see (on the remote) my branch after this update?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Not very clear. Is that a `rebase` that you want to achieve? Do: Checkout `bugfix`. Right click on `master`. Rebase current branch on (this commit).

Comment: Maybe, I'm not so used to GIT, I started just a few weeks ago.

Is a rebase the right command to do that?

I'm sorry that the question is not clear, if I can make it clearer, I'm happy to do that.

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It would be great if you could rephrase your question as it is not clear what you're trying to achieve.
Typically you don't rebase already pushed branches, because your local copy would diverge from the remote copy; and you will need to force-push (overwrite the remote history). Force-push it ok when you do it on your fork, but typically not ok when done on the main trunk.